# YA Sci-Fi about a young girl who is a confidential interpreter and ends up sentenced to death?

Tags: story-identification, aliens, young-adult

I am looking for an older (probably 1990's or before) young adult sci-fi novel. The plot, as best I can remember, is that the female protagonist is some sort of human "universal translator" but she is bound to absolute confidentiality about what she translates, on pain of death. However, she finds out about some sort of horrible treasonous or genocidal plot by one alien race so she decides to break confidentiality even though it means she'll be executed.

It was fairly melodramatic so I'm sure it's a YA novel, other than that I have no idea....

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/89486/children-raised-collectively-girl-taken-to-be-translator-for-aliens

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/81723/90s-sci-fi-book-of-a-world-where-women-had-no-rights-but-they-act-as-translator

Comment: I'm afraid that's not it...the protagonist of this particular novel was still a teenager, possibly a VERY young teenager. Thanks for the suggestion though, it's a good read!

Comment: It was a long-shot, hence why posted as a comment not an answer :-)

Answer (score 5):

[The Stolen Law](http://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-06-024118-6) by Anne Mason.

---

Kira is a teenage xenolinguist who discovers that one alien group is mistranslating laws to make them more restrictive/different in intent.

While investigating, she discovers that they're plotting to kill another group of aliens, but **revealing confidential information is punishable by the death penalty.**

[image]

I loved this book and its prequel The Dancing Meteorite when I was younger!

Comment: THIS IS IT! I even recognize the cover. Thank you so much NinjaPenguin. I kind of love you right now. I hope that's not super weird. But I've been looking for SO LONG.